# KafkaProducer - Ordering guarantee

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Can anyone help me in picking up the better option out of the below two to provide the ordering guarantee

1. Idempotent Producer
2. Producer with max.inflight.requests.per.connection=1

I want to know that whether anyone had done any analysis of how the latency numbers would be for different producers and what are the factors that affect those latency numbers.

Comment: AFAIK, these are not exclusive options, and ultimately depend on what delivery guarantees you want. I don't think idempotent producers are strictly ordered across requests

Comment: Idempotent Producer do give ordering guarantees across requests. I don't understand why you made that statement. Pls correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: To my knowledge, it avoids duplication and dropped messages, not guarantees order until you also include max in flight config to the idempotent producer